# Grouping by all columns except one to count distinct values on the remaining column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have `table A` with five rows and the following values:

```
Column1  Column2  Column3  Column4
-------  -------  -------  -------
anna     ben      cat      d
anna     ben      cat      e
anna     ben      cat      f
gina     hugh     ken      m
gina     hugh     ken      p
```

I want to add another column called `Column5`. The value of `Column 5` will be 3 for the first 3 rows and 2 on the next 2 rows:

```
Column1  Column2  Column3  Column4  Column5
-------  -------  -------  -------  -------
anna     ben      cat      d        3
anna     ben      cat      e        3
anna     ben      cat      f        3
gina     hugh     ken      m        2
gina     hugh     ken      p        2
```

How I did this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT COUNT (DISTINCT t1.Column4) AS Column5,
Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4
FROM TableA AS t1
GROUP BY Column1, Column2, Column3;
```

This doesn't work:

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Procedure COUNT, Line 29
>   Column 'Column4' invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an
>   aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Any help please? Much appreciated.

PS: If I add `Column4` in the group by clause, I get only values of "1" in the result table in `Column5`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One other way to do what you want would be to select distinct rows first, then apply the windowed COUNT() function:

```
WITH distinctrows AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT
    Column1,
    Column2,
    Column3,
    Column4
  FROM TableA
)
SELECT
  Column1,
  Column2,
  Column3,
  Column4,
  COUNT(Column4) OVER (PARTITION BY Column1, Column2, Column3) AS Column5
FROM distinctrows
;
```

Comment: One difference with mine is that rows which are duplicated for `Column4` within a group will only appear once in the result using this answer and multiple times using my answer. The OP hasn't given an example of this in their example data though.

Comment: But they *have* included `DISTINCT` in their query's SELECT clause. I was first puzzled by it, but now I think I can see what it is there for.

Comment: Marvellous, I applied this answer and it worked and fits and purpose. You were both wonderful.

Answer (score 3):

If you didn't need `DISTINCT` this would be easy.

```
SELECT Column1,
       Column2,
       Column3,
       Column4,
       Count(Column4) OVER (partition BY Column1, Column2, Column3) AS Column5
FROM   TableA AS t1
```

But windowed aggregates in SQL Server don't currently support `DISTINCT` so you can use

```
WITH CTE
     AS (SELECT Column1,
                Column2,
                Column3,
                Count(DISTINCT Column4) AS Column5
         FROM   TableA
         GROUP  BY Column1,
                   Column2,
                   Column3)
SELECT A.Column1,
       A.Column2,
       A.Column3,
       A.Column4,
       C.Column5
FROM   TableA A
       JOIN CTE C
         ON A.Column1 = C.Column1
            AND A.Column2 = C.Column2
            AND A.Column3 = C.Column3
```

(I have assumed the columns are not nullable for simplicity)

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT t1.Column4) AS Column5,
Column1, Column2, Column3
FROM TableA AS t1
GROUP BY Column1, Column2, Column3;
```

Comment: Thank you, Andy! This works, **except** that it eliminates Column4 from the result, and **I am interested in the information on Column4**, as well. So **the trick is how to add Column4 in the select list, but not in the group by clause - without receiving that error**!

Comment: From what I just read, it may have to do with not using the 'only full group by mode' so that I can add Column4 in the select clause without getting that error. I am investigating this solution and in the meantime I hope to see other suggestions here. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
;WITH 
  countCol4 As
(
    SELECT  Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4
    ,       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4
                ORDER BY Column4)   As Col4Count
    FROM    TableA  As t1
)
SELECT  Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4
,       COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY Column1, Column2, Column3) As Column5
FROM    countCol4
WHERE   Col4Count = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from 'unsetting' the "only full group by" mode which I just read about but haven't tried yet, I just applied the following faster solution, it's a trick, I did this to avoid getting that error:

```
 SELECT 
     COUNT (DISTINCT t1.Column4) AS Column5, Column1, Column2, Column3, MAX(Column4) AS Column4
 FROM TableA AS t1 
 GROUP BY Column1, Column2, Column3;
```

I have character values on Column4. This seems OK and I now see values ranging from 1-6 in Column5, as I properly expected. Thanks!

Warning: This is not a good answer. See comments below for reason.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure but I've got a suspicion that the *Only full GROUP BY* mode you've just read about has to do with MySQL and *not* with SQL Server.

Comment: Bingo, you are very right Andriy, I just the article again and indeed there is a mention of MySql there, so that doesn't apply here. Still I am curious, why there is this obligation to include all columns in Group by that aren't new or applied an aggregated function to. In SAS which is another database system , this isn't compulsory and my statement above wouldn't have triggered that error.

Comment: How do you feel about my solution and about this obligation I mentioned earlier?

Comment: This won't return the results you asked for in your question. It will only return 2 rows for your example data not the 5 in your desired results.

Comment: Martin Smith, why? I thought it did at first glance. And do you know how to return the correct result?

Comment: In MySQL the "Only full GROUP BY" mode is off by default, so your original statement would "work" there too. But you would still get one row per group of `Column1, Column2, Column3`, not all the rows, and also the value for `Column4` would be undetermined.

Comment: RE: "Why?" because it returns one row per group.

Comment: Martin Smith, yes, you are right, thank you for pointing that out. Thank you Andriy for pointing the same! So how can I make it return the proper number of rows per group, now?